# PXE: file not found - but why?

Tags: ubuntu, pxe

I am trying to set up PXE boot for Ubuntu 22.04 Server, following [these instructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/z19yz9/ubuntu_2204_lts_jammy_jellyfish_pxe/). This is my `/srv/tftp`:

```
root@vogon:~# ll /srv/tftp
total 1444
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jul 15  2022 boot/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jul  1  2022 debian/
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root    4096 Jul  8  2022 debian-installer/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      36 Jul  8  2022 grub.cfg -> debian-installer/amd64/grub/grub.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9278 Jul  1  2022 grub.cfg.bk
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1426816 Jan 25 13:44 grubx64.efi
drwx------ 2 root root   16384 Jul  8  2022 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jan 25 13:22 save/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 Jan 25 12:52 ubuntu/
```

The idea is that I will be able to choose from a number of distros, and this works for Debian 11 and Ubuntu 20.04; I now want to add Ubuntu 22.04 - this is my `grub.cfg`:

```
root@vogon:~# cat /srv/tftp/grub.cfg
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
set gfxpayload=text
set timeout=-1

menuentry 'Debian 11'{
        set background_color=black
        linux    /debian/11/amd64/linux priority=low vga=788 ---
        initrd   /debian/11/amd64/initrd.gz
}

menuentry "Ubuntu 20.04" {
  linux /ubuntu/20.04/amd64/linux only-ubiquity ip=dhcp ---
  initrd /ubuntu/20.04/amd64/initrd.gz
}

menuentry "Ubuntu 22.04 Server" {
  linux /srv/tftp/ubuntu/22.04-srv/vmlinuz url=https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso only-ubiquity ip=dhcp ---
  initrd=/srv/tftp/ubuntu/22.04-srv/initrd
}
```

The menu shows up fine, but when I choose `Ubuntu 22.04 Server`, I briefly see the message `File not found` - nothing about which file, though. The `linux ...` line for this entry has been through several permutations, which all show the same error. The last file mentioned in `syslog` is `/srv/tftp/ubuntu/22.04-srv/vmlinuz`:

```
...
Jan 25 13:18:52 vogon in.tftpd[376344]: RRQ from 192.168.50.96 filename grubx64.efi
Jan 25 13:18:52 vogon in.tftpd[376345]: RRQ from 192.168.50.96 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst
Jan 25 13:18:52 vogon in.tftpd[376346]: RRQ from 192.168.50.96 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst
Jan 25 13:18:52 vogon in.tftpd[376347]: RRQ from 192.168.50.96 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst
Jan 25 13:18:52 vogon in.tftpd[376348]: RRQ from 192.168.50.96 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst
Jan 25 13:18:52 vogon in.tftpd[376349]: RRQ from 192.168.50.96 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/grub.cfg
Jan 25 13:19:00 vogon in.tftpd[376358]: RRQ from 192.168.50.96 filename /srv/tftp/ubuntu/22.04-srv/vmlinuz
...
```

My suspicion is that `vmlinux` is loaded, but the `url=...` isn't understood - but what should it be instead?

Comment: YYour path in 22.04 is absolute, the one in the others relative.

Comment: @stoney good point actually - I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `grubx64.efi` is requested from your TFTP server, it provides the file `/srv/tftp/grubx64.efi`.

When `/debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst` is requested, it provides the file `/srv/tftp/debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst`. Can you see the pattern?

Your TFTP server seems to add the `/srv/tftp/` prefix to the pathnames of all the requests it receives, effectively restricting TFTP access to `/srv/tftp/` and directories under it only. You could say that `/srv/tftp` is your server's *TFTP root directory*.

When writing the menu entry for Ubuntu 22.04, you have written that prefix in, unlike the other menu entries. When the TFTP server gets a request for `/srv/tftp/ubuntu/22.04-srv/vmlinuz`, it will add the prefix again... and ends up trying to read `/srv/tftp/srv/tftp/ubuntu/22.04-srv/vmlinuz`, which obviously doesn't exist.

I'd suggest changing your `/srv/tftp/grub.cfg` entry for Ubuntu 22.04 to this:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 22.04 Server" {
  linux /ubuntu/22.04-srv/vmlinuz url=https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso only-ubiquity ip=dhcp ---
  initrd /ubuntu/22.04-srv/initrd
}
```

The filenames after the keywords `linux` and `initrd` tell the PXE-booted GRUB to download those files over TFTP, so those pathnames must be relative to your server's TFTP root.

At this point, `url=` is just a data string that will be passed as-is without interpretation to the kernel that GRUB is trying to boot. Once the kernel starts up and the scripts and tools in the `initrd` file begin executing (in other words, in the initramfs boot phase) the string is retrieved through `/proc/cmdline`. I don't have Ubuntu network install `initrd` file at hand so I cannot extract it to confirm, but I would guess the presence of the `url=` option will trigger some script to use a tool like `curl` or `wget` to download the contents of that URL to a RAM disk.

Since the URL specifies `https://`, it has nothing to do with TFTP. If your internet connection is not the fastest, you might want to download the ISO once, host it in some reasonably local HTTP or HTTPS server, and adjust the `url=` parameter accordingly. That should speed up at least the initial part of the installation process.